# SQL Server join only one record

Tags: sql-server, join, row

How write proper SQL to return only first joined row others NULLs

```
    I have             SQL server JOIN         Desired
  T1      T2              T3                      T3
   A    A AAAA            A AAAA                 A AAAA
   A    B BBBB            A AAAA                 A
   A    C CCCC           A AAAA                 A
   A    D DDDD          A AAAA                 A
```

My SQL string from stored procedure

```
SELECT OQ.*, 
SitesS.Siteaddress STOREADR 
FROM @OQ OQ, dbo.Sites SitesS 
WHERE OQ.STORE = SitesS.Sitenumber
```

i have store order list which must be joined with address database, i dont want repeat same address every row on same store

Comment: Hard to say what you are doing incorrectly, when you don't show what your are doing. Show your SQL.

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to say, or what your explanation is trying to describe. **SHOW YOUR SQL** if you want help.

Comment: Please describe your ques(what to achieve). Post some sample queries which you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is rather odd what you are trying to achieve.

Given that your input is this:

```
DECLARE @T1 TABLE (id VARCHAR(10))
DECLARE @T2 TABLE (id VARCHAR(10), address VARCHAR(20))

INSERT @T1 VALUES 
    ('A'),
    ('A'),
    ('A'),
    ('A'),
    ('B'),
    ('B')

INSERT @T2 VALUES 
    ('A', 'AAAA'),
    ('B', 'BBBB'),
    ('C', 'CCCC'),
    ('D', 'DDDD')
```

the following query:

```
SELECT id, CASE WHEN rowNum = 1 THEN address
                WHEN rowNum > 1 THEN NULL
           END
FROM (
SELECT t1.id, t2.address, 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t1.id ORDER BY t1.id) AS rowNum
FROM @T1 AS t1
INNER JOIN @T2 AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.id) t
```

yields this output:

```
id   address
------------
A    AAAA
A    NULL
A    NULL
A    NULL
B    BBBB
B    NULL
```

Comment: Worked! For me its enough SELECT OQ.*, CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY STORE) = 1 THEN SitesS.Siteaddress ELSE NULL END STOREADR